# How to install thai language/keyboard support for Ubuntu phone Bq 4.5 Aquaris

Tags: keyboard, language-support

How to install thai language/keyboard support for Ubuntu phone Bq 4.5 aquaris?

I know it is possible for normal ubuntu but how to do it in ubuntu phone as apt-get install does not work under terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think the reason why Thai isn't supported yet is that it's not sufficiently translated for the phone.

http://projects.davidplanella.org/stats/vivid/th

Comment: I think the main need for the thai language is just the keyboard to write thai in a browser. Not to use the phone with thai language.

Comment: @user401863: I see. If I was you, I'd join the [Ubuntu Phone team](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-phone) and suggest it on the mailing list.